# Is there an infinite dimensional Stein's lemma?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, calculus-of-variations, schwartz-distributions, gaussian

[Classical Stein's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein%27s_lemma) says that if $\mathbf{X}$ is a centered Gaussian random vector and $g$ is a function which is nice enough, we have
$$
\mathbb{E} \, X_i \, g ( \mathbf{X} )
= \sum_k \operatorname{cov} (X_i, X_k)\, \mathbb{E} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_k}. 
$$
I wonder if there is some infinite dimensional analogue of this lemma, saying something like
$$
\mathbb{E} \, X ( t ) \, g ( X) = \int \mathbb{E} \operatorname{cov}(X(t), X(s)) D_{X(s)} g \ ds
$$
if $X$ is a continuous real-valued Gaussian process satisfying some assumptions, $g$ is some nice enough functional and $D$ is some derivative-like operator.

I know that my question is rather vague, I was curious since I needed to compute expectations like the one on the left and Stein's lemma immediately popped in mind.

---

**Mostly unrelated question.** Most of the sources demand that $g$ be continuously differentiable for the classical lemma to hold. It seems that this is not necessary. It should be enough for these derivatives $\partial_k g$ to exist in the distributional sense, because they are immediately integrated against normal density. Is there some source where the lemma is formulated like this?

Comment: Should $\mathbb{E} \, X_i \, g ( \mathbf{X} ) = \mathbb{E} \, (X_i-\mu_i) \, g ( \mathbf{X} )$ or does that not matter? Wikipedia uses the latter definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein%27s_lemma

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal, I just forgot the word "centered", thanks for the remark.

Comment: Assuming that $g(X)$ can be approximated well enough by smooth enough functions of restrictions of the random function $X$ to finite sets, you can use the "finite-dimensional" Stein lemma.

Comment: Yes the integration by parts formula in Malliavin calculus eg.  in "Stein's method on Wiener chaos" (https://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.2940.pdf) eq. (1.23).

Comment: Theorem 5.1.8 on page 209 of the book "Gaussian Measures" by Bogachev provides a generalization to possibly infinite dimensional spaces.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I have found what I needed under the name of Novikov-Furutsu theorem in the following papers:

1. K. I. Mamis, [New formulas for moments and functions of the multivariate normal distribution extending Stein's lemma and Isserlis theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.00189)
2. G. A. Athanassoulis and K. I. Mamis, [Extensions of the Novikov–Furutsu theorem, obtained by using Volterra functional calculus](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1402-4896/ab10b5) by
3. M. D. Donsker and J. L. Lions, [Fréchet-Volterra variational equations, boundary value problems, and function space integrals](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/acta-mathematica/volume-108/issue-none/Fr%C3%A9chet-Volterra-variational-equations-boundary-value-problems-and-function-space/10.1007/BF02545767.full)
4. M. Scott, [Applied Stochastic Processes in Science and Engineering](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Emscott/Little_Notes.pdf), Lecture Notes, University of Waterloo, (2013).

Formula (45) of the first paper reads:
$$
\mathbb{E} \{ g [ X ] \, X_t \} = \mu ( t ) \, \mathbb{E} \{ g [ X ] \} + \int_0^T C ( t, s ) \, \mathbb{E} \left\{ \frac{\delta g[X]}{\delta X_s} \right\} \, ds,
$$
where $\delta / \delta X_s$ is something called Volterra-Fréchet derivative, $\mu$ is the mean function and $C(t, s)$ is the covariance.

The third paper gives essentially the same formula (1.21): for a centered Gaussian process with covariance function $\rho$ holds
$$
\mathbb{E}_y^\rho \{ y ( \tau ) \, F [ y ] \}
= \int_0^t \rho ( \tau, s ) \, \mathbb{E} \left\{ \frac{\delta F [ y ]}{\delta y ( s )} \right\} \, ds.
$$
This paper also introduces the Volterra-Fréchet derivatives.

Finally, Donsker and Lions write that for the Brownian motion the formula
$$
\mathbb{E}_z^w \{ z ( \tau ) \, F [ z ] \}
= \int_0^t \min ( \tau, s ) \, \mathbb{E} \left\{ \frac{\delta F}{\delta z ( s )} \right\} \, ds
$$
goes back to the paper [The first variation of an indefinite Wiener integral](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1951-002-06/S0002-9939-1951-0045937-X/S0002-9939-1951-0045937-X.pdf) by Cameron.

---

I wonder if there is a modern standard framework for formulas like this? I still fail to see how they fit into the Malliavin calculus...